# ZSH isn't following powerlevel9k theme

Tags: zsh

I installed the `powerlevel9k` theme 3 days ago. It was working just fine, but since yesterday my prompt is not displaying the theme. It looks like this.

[image: the appearance right now]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the issue by adding this to my `.zshrc` file after the theme variable assignment:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=('status' 'load' 'ram_joined' 'time')
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Now the theme is working properly

[image]